# Manage world lifetime with cucumber rust

Tags: rust, cucumber, lifetime

I made a rust lib I want to test with Cucumber-Rust.

In part of that lib, I have some structs declared with lifetimes, as:

```
pub struct Intersection<'a> {
     time: f64,
     object: &'a Shape,
 }
```

My lib is working fine. But I want to test it with Cucumber. So I need a world struct that may contains any data my tests can manipulate. So I made this :

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum WorldEntry {
    Tuple(Tuple),
    Double(f64),
    Color(Color),
    Canvas(Canvas),
    PPM(String),
    Matrix(Matrix),
    Ray(Ray),
    Shape(Shape),
    Intersect(Intersection),
    Interset(Intersections),
    Hit(Option<Intersection>),
    Light(PointLight),
    Material(Material),
}

#[derive(Debug, World)]
#[world(init = Self::new)]
pub struct CucumberWorld {
    all_entries: HashMap<String, WorldEntry>,
}
```

Of course, compiler is complaining :

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> tests/world/mod.rs:17:15
   |
17 |     Intersect(Intersection),
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
   |
8  ~ pub enum WorldEntry<'a> {
9  |     Tuple(Tuple),
 ...
16 |     Shape(Shape),
17 ~     Intersect(Intersection<'a>),
   |
```

So I've added the lifetime, just as the Compiler suggest:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum WorldEntry<'a> {
    Tuple(Tuple),
    Double(f64),
    Color(Color),
    Canvas(Canvas),
    PPM(String),
    Matrix(Matrix),
    Ray(Ray),
    Shape(Shape),
    Intersect(Intersection<'a>),
    Interset(Intersections<'a>),
    Hit(Option<Intersection<'a>>),
    Light(PointLight),
    Material(Material),
}

#[derive(Debug, World)]
#[world(init = Self::new)]
pub struct CucumberWorld<'a> {
    all_entries: HashMap<String, WorldEntry<'a>>,
}
```

But the compiler still complains, and the message is cryptic:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> tests/world/mod.rs:26:12
   |
26 | pub struct CucumberWorld<'a> {
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
   |
26 | pub struct CucumberWorld<'a><'a><'a> {
   |                         ++++
```

What should I do ?

Comment: The type with the lifetime is valid ([see here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3f5a0d0a6c79db203daad63876f7af3)) so my guess is that the macros from cucumber are broken when the type has a lifetime, it probably only supports 'static lifetime structs. You could user a `CucumberWorld<'static>` but this isn't helpful if you have things returning Intersections with a shorter lifetime. What exactly do you mean by "I need a world struct that may contains any data my tests can manipulate" ? Can you include a complete example?

Comment: A cucumber test (a scenario) is divided into steps. Each step is provided a struct (a world, or context) for storing data. So for a typical scenario, you have several steps for storing data (steps "given"), one or several another steps for the action you want to test (steps "when"), and lastly some tests to asserts that everything was as expected (steps "then"). Each step is a rust function, and the first arg is a mutable ref to the world. A new world objected is created for each scenario.